# Why function getPrice() called only one time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

Why function getPrice() called only one time in my code? I think it must called every time when the **telegrambot** gets message. Or i am wrong?

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare')
const nightmare = Nightmare({show: true})

const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api')
const TOKEN = ''

const bot = new TelegramBot(TOKEN, {polling: true})
console.log('Bot has been started...')

let price 

 function getPrice(){
    nightmare
        .goto('https://uk.investing.com/commodities/real-time-futures')
        .evaluate(()=>{
            let gold = document.querySelector('.pid-68-last').innerText
            let goldAug20 = document.querySelector('.pid-8830-last').innerText
            let diff = Math.abs( gold.replace(',','') - goldAug20.replace(',',''))
            return diff.toFixed(2)
        })
        .end()
        .then(data =>{
            price = data
            //console.log(price)
            return nightmare
        })
    
  }

  bot.on('message', (msg) => {
    getPrice()
    bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, price)
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that `getPrice()` should get called every time the `message` event triggers, so it's possible that the event is only triggering once. Maybe add a console log to verify that the event is firing on each message.

There is an additional problem with your code, however, which is that the `price` variable is going to get set *after* the event, because it is async. I'm not familiar with the Nightmare library, but based on your code it looks like you could make some simple changes to use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) in order to get it to work:

```js
 // Add the 'async' keyword to make this an asynchronous function function
 async function getPrice(){
    // return the "promise" resulting from your chained method calls
    return nightmare
        .goto('https://uk.investing.com/commodities/real-time-futures')
        .evaluate(()=>{
            let gold = document.querySelector('.pid-68-last').innerText
            let goldAug20 = document.querySelector('.pid-8830-last').innerText
            let diff = Math.abs( gold.replace(',','') - goldAug20.replace(',',''))
            return diff.toFixed(2)
        })
        .end()
        .then(data =>{
            price = data
            //console.log(price)
            return nightmare
        })
    
  }

  // Make the callback asynchronous with the 'async' keyword
  bot.on('message', async (msg) => {
    // Use the 'await' keyword to pause execution until the promise
    // is resolved (and therefore "price" is set)
    await getPrice()
    bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, price)
  })
```

I'm not sure if the rest of your code will behave as expected, but that's how you'd get the asynchronous stuff to work the way you intend! Definitely spend some time reading up on [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises). They take practice to get used to, but are essential in Javascript!

Comment: Why not move the bot.sendMessage call to the async function with msg.chat.id as a argument? This way, There's no need to wait for getPrice.

Comment: Thank you, it helps me. Now function called in time, but still one time